# Get Count for each Joined Record

Tags: sql, count

I have 2 tables which I'd like to join and..

```
A:
ID Otherfields..
1  ...
2
3
4


B:
ID aId  Otherfields..
1  1    ...
2  1
3  2
4  1
```

So I'm perfectly capable of joining them by a.Id but how do get I get the count for the matches in Table B, like:

```
a.id  count(b)
1     3
2     1
```

I figured it must be something with count() over() but cannot recall the exact use.

Thanks!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Oracle - isnt this a commonly solvable problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT 
  A.ID, COUNT(b.ID)
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.Id = b.aID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Comment: Silly me, never thought about adding a group by thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can have

```
SELECT A.ID, COUNT(b.ID)
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.Id = b.aID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

This will give you all `a.ID`s that don't exist in `b.ID` and hence show their count as 0.

E.g.,

```
ID   Count
1    3
2    1
3    0
4    0
```